# How to prevent an expensive API to be consumed by spiders and crawlers?

Tags: php

I am using an API that is pretty expensive. Each call costs about 1 cent. I noticed that visits from spiders and crawlers generate thousands of calls to that API and I am being charged for them. Is there a way to block the section of the webpage that shows content generated by that API, in the way that only actual visitors can see it and no API calls will be generated when the webpage is being crawled?

Comment: Can you provide more info on how the API is consumed by your users? Mobile phones, javascript sites, etc.?

Comment: Are the API calls spesific for each visitor? If not then implement caching so you only run one request each week/day/hour (whichever fits the data set) and reuse the data for each visitor. If they are visitor spesific then are you able to lock down the api calls for only authenticated users?

Comment: API calls are generated by search keywords provided by users when they try to search for something on my website, via desktop or mobile. Search results pages are not being blocked by robots.txt, and I don't want to do so. The problem is that i have 2 million pages indexed on Google, that's why the API is being consumed. I could block a section of the page from Google, but there are other spiders and crawlers.

Comment: Ok, bots will probably just search for random text strings so caching that will be close to impossible. Maybe add reCAPTCHA for unauthenticated users, or some other detection method to avoid "garbage" searches

Answer (score 0):

You could do the API call in front-end instead of doing it server-side. For example, during the page load, do an AJAX request to your server that will make a call to the API and return the data.

Presumably, the spiders and crawlers just parse the source code and do not execute the JS, thus they will not execute the AJAX request and you will not be charged. However, if some of your visitors do not have JS enabled, you should provide them a way to get the results anyway.

Apart from this, what you could do if you want to reduce your cost is to implement a caching system so that you do not do the same call multiple times in a row to the API. You can define the caching time according to the criticality of fresh data.

Comment: The AJAX request sounds good. How do I implement it? Let's say that the I would like to include/not include a certain php file depending if the visit is coming from a human or from a crawler.

Comment: @Zetal, if you want to check in Ajax if the visitor is a crawler or a human you can do it by using regular expressions on the visitor's user agent.

Answer (score 0):

There are some many methods to prevent from crawlers crawl your site / specific pages. The problem is that you need to define which kind of crawlers you want to block as there are many types of them. As a starting point, Google & Bing do not respect robots.txt setting for the crawl-delays (you can change the crawl rate of those by changing this manually in their dashboard).

As you mentioned you are working with PHP, well if you are using Apache than you can try the Apache access log - it registers all requests Apache receives - analyze the log files and you can which crawlers are making all of the traffic you are talking about (when you know which crawlers make the heavy traffic you know which one you can kill by using blocking them using .htaccess file - you can redirect web requests coming from specific IP addresses or user agents to 403 http error or any desired redirect output)

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to block crawlers. I just want to avoid the API call when the visit is coming from a crawler, but still keep the rest of the content on the webpage available to be crawled.

Comment: @Zetal, I think you are not implementing what you are trying to do in a right way. If you have a webpage you want to be crawled but this webpage also uses an API than the only you can do is maybe use a cache system or limit the number of requests per each visitor. Usually, you won't have free to crawl web pages with a bunch of API calls.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this but still looking for better ideas:

```
<?php
if (preg_match('/slurp|inktomisearch|[Gg]rub|[Bb]ot|archiver|[Ss]qworm/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
include("no-api-call.php");
}  else {
include("yes-api-call.php");
}
?>
```